# Why does a bird sitting on an electric wire suddenly fly off when a high current is passed through the wire? Or does it?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I looked for an answer to this question [online](https://clay6.com/qa/74753/as-soon-as-current-is-switched-on-a-high-voltage-line-the-bird-sitting-on-i) but the explanation seemed rather wrong and unconvincing too. It said that it is due to "induced current flowing through the body of the bird."
It explained it like this:
“When the current is switched on, induced current flows through the body of the bird. The induced current flows in the opposite direction through the wings of the bird. Hence the wings experience a force of mutual repulsion. The wings spread and hence the bird flies.”

A Quora user said birds don't even fly off when a high current passes through electric wires and that they just still as ever. And how would an induced current even develop in the body of the bird? Birds aren't "conductors", right? Okay, I'm just a high school student with a pretty limited understanding of electromagnetic induction so I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me and correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: First of all, high voltage power lines don't have current "switching on". Current is always flowing unless power is restored following a power outage.

Comment: What is your reference for your first paragraph? Who said these things? I would think that since there is a very small potential difference between two points on the same wire a bird's legs length apart that we wouldn't get any current flowing into the bird.

Comment: How do you know that birds fly off when 'high current' passes through the wire? Has an experiment been done which proves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really doubting any significant current is induced in the bird. After all, they are quite happy to perch on wires with 60 HZ at really quite large current and voltage.

[This](http://www.science.smith.edu/~jcardell/Courses/EGR220/ElecPwr_HSW.html) web site says that lines used for 100's of km use up to 765,000 volts.  Since these sorts of lines often carry 100's of mega Watts, that means currents of hundreds of amps. So, the normal every-day kind of thing going through such a wire is already quite large. If anything was going to get induced in the birds, they would feel it all of the time.

Suddenly turning on the power will produce changes in the cable. The cable does get heated by the current, achieving some sort of equilibrium between heating and cooling to the surroundings. So when the power is turned on the cable will start to heat. As it heats it will likely sway, heat unevenly, and "pop", and probably have little disturbances run along the wire. This could easily be quite surprising to the birds and cause them to startle.